# Transparent NSMenu

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, opacity, nsmenuitem, nsmenu

I'm trying to change the opacity of a NSMenu, I made custom NSMenuItems and changed their opacity but there is still the white color of menu behinde them, I'm looking for a way too change the color and opacity of the menu background. I was wondering if it's even possible?

Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think there is an elegant way to do that. [`NSMenu`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSMenu_Class/Reference/Reference.html) isn't a subclass of `NSView`. The rendering view is probably a private variable of the menu object.

[`NSMenuItem`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSMenuItem_Class/Reference/Reference.html) has a `view` property that you can use. Try setting a custom view (if you don't already) and later find the menu's view by calling `menuItem.view.superview`. Then set that view's `alpha` property.

Alternatively you could try to find the private `view` property of `NSMenu` with a tool like `class-dump`. Note that using private variables is never a good idea. Especially if you're planning to release the app on the App Store.

Comment: Thank you for answer. Using the superview is not working. I'm trying to do it without private variables.